# Swashbuckle Swagger url from http to https .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

My API is an HTTP API (not HTTPS) developped in ASP.NET.

Nevertheless, when deployed in the DMZ, there is something, somewhere on the network, not under my responsability, that only accept HTTPS and act as a reverse proxy to my HTTP API.

This leads to the swagger UI misbahaving.

The URL to access the swagger UI is "https://external_public_name/api/swagger/ui/index#/" but he one in the text field in the green ribbon is "http://external_public_name/api/swagger/docs/v1".

Therefore, the page is blank, with the error at the console

> Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://external_public_name/api/swagger/ui/index' was loaded over
> HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
> 'http://external_public_name/api/swagger/docs/v1'. This request has
> been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Replacing, manually the URL in the textbox with HTTPS is working fine.

Where should I change something to update that URL (maybe at runtime)?

P.S.: I already had to rewrite the SwaggerConfig.cs as SwaggerConfig.vb to be able to use it.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports System.Web.Http.Description
Imports Swashbuckle.Application
Imports Swashbuckle.Swagger

<Assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(GetType(SwaggerConfig), "Register")>

Public Class SwaggerConfig
    Public Class KnownSubTypesDocumentFilter
        Implements IDocumentFilter

        Public Sub Apply(swaggerDoc As SwaggerDocument, schemaRegistry As SchemaRegistry, apiExplorer As IApiExplorer) Implements IDocumentFilter.Apply
            schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(GetType(BookController.BookList))
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Shared Sub Register()
        Dim thisAssembly = GetType(SwaggerConfig).Assembly

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableSwagger(
            Function(c)
                c.Schemes({"https"})
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "api")
                c.DocumentFilter(Of KnownSubTypesDocumentFilter)()
                Return c
            End Function).EnableSwaggerUi(
            Function(ui)
                ui.DocumentTitle("Skippy's API")
                ui.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List)
                ui.SupportedSubmitMethods()
                Return ui
            End Function)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing your swagger configuration

Comment: Nothing fancy, I took the SwaggerConfig.cs, rewrote everything in vb and uncommented what I wanted. I've added the file without the comments in my question.

Comment: Did you try replacing http with https in the swaggerconfig.cs:

c.ResolveBasePathUsing(
                    (req) =>
                    {
                        var swaggerUrl = req.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + subdirectory + req.GetConfiguration().VirtualPathRoot.TrimEnd('/');

 if (!req.RequestUri.Host.Contains("localhost"))
 {
  swaggerUrl = swaggerUrl.Replace("http", "https");
 }
  return swaggerUrl;
  });

Comment: ResolveBasePathUsing is replaced by RootUrl in Swashbuckle 5 but it is not working. It is changing the URL in the address bar, adding /swagger at the end to resolve the FullURI but not the URL shown in the textbox inside the page.